# Check python list contains objects with completely unique id's?

Tags: python, list, sorting, set

If I have a list of random python objects:

```
a = [object_1, object_2, "lala", 5, 6, 3, 9, object_3]
```

How do I check if they are all unique? objects 1, 2 and 3 may all point to the same object for example. I have thought about using id() and converting the list to a list of integer id's but it seems overkill.

By unique I mean the objects all have different id's by calling, say, id(object_1). Even lists have a unique id despite not being hashable.

Comment: But two equal numbers/string are *not* per se the same object: for example `a = "foobar"; b = "foo"; b += "bar"; a is b` will return `False`.

Comment: can you provide an example of `object_1`, ... and define *uniqueness*?

Comment: If you want to inspect that the objects are all unique then it is more `s = set(); return not any(i in s or s.add(i) for i in map(id, a))`.

Comment: By unique I mean the objects all have different id's by calling, say, id(object_1). I have given an answer also (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51765552/6782278)

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
a = [object_1, object_2, "lala", 5, 6, 3, 9, object_3]
def is_unique(l):
    return len(set(l))==len(l)
print(is_unique(a))
```

Or:

```
def is_unique(l):
    return False not in [True if l.count(i)==1 else False for i in l]
print(is_unique(a))
```

Or:

```
from collections import Counter
def is_unique(l):
    return list(Counter(l).values()).count(1)==len(l)
print(is_unique(a))
```

Comment: This assumes `object_1`, `object_2` etc are hashable. This isn't clear.

Comment: `list(set(l))==l` Not necessarily. Converting to `set` might scramble the order of elements. Compare the `len` instead.

Comment: @tobias_k Edited my answer

Comment: This suffers from the same problem the other answer has: not all objects can be put in a `set`, for example a `dict` object can *not* be hashed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Edited mine

Comment: all objects are id'able though. By unique I mean the objects all have different id's by calling, say, id(object_1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def check(objectsList):
    typeList = [type(object) for object in objectsList]

    if len(typeList) != len(set(typeList)):
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: This only looks at object types. Not sure this is what OP wants.

Comment: @jpp You're right, but I don't quite understand what the OP's actually asking for. We don't know how the OP's defining 'unique' here so I'm assuming that they want unique types only.

Comment: By unique I mean the objects all have different id's by calling, say, id(object_1)

Answer (score 0):

if list is `a = [object_1, object_2, "lala", 5, 6, 3, 9, object_3]`
check frequency and you will know which ones are unique

```
    frequency_of_elements = {i:a.count(i) for i in a}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess manually check every object is better? At least it can overcome the problem of unhashable.

```
def check(_list):
    from collections import Hashable
    hash_set = {}
    id_set = {}
    for item in _list:
        if isinstance(item, Hashable):
            hash_code = hash(item)
            if hash_code in hash_set:
                return False
            hash_set.add(hash_code)
        else:
            id_code = id(item)
            if id_code in id_set:
                return False
            id_set.add(id_code)
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically, you can achieve the same thing by just ignoring the "hashable" check and just getting the id for everything? see my answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51765552/6782278

Comment: Something "equals" but have different ids. For example, two lists contains the same items have different ids.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using a python set. A python set creates a unique list of entries from a python list. this can be numbers, strings or custom python objects. Then simply compare the length of this to the original list and see if it's the same or not.

Edit: I now realise that some objects aren't hashable (like list), you can amend this function by first converting the list of objects to a list of unique id's

```
   def check_all_objects_unique(objects: List[Any]) -> bool:
       object_ids = [id(object) for object in objects]
       unique_objects = set(object_ids)
       if len(unique_objects) == len(objects):
           return True
       elif len(unique_objects) < len(objects):
           return False
```

Comment: Not all objects per se can be hashed. For example if one of the elements is a `dict` or `list`, then there is a problem.

Comment: Or it could be written as: `return not any(map(lambda L, S=set(): L in S or S.add(L), objects))`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have amended my answer!